# Is Android blocking UDP packets from outsite?

Tags: java, android, udp

I have just created a simple application, that sends a message to the server, and server replies back. Everything is good in local network, but when I am trying to do the same outsite my network, it is working in following way:

1. Client sends packet
2. Server receives packet
3. Server sends packet
4. Client doesn't receives packet.

To send anwser packet I am using InetAddress delivered with DatagramPacket.

What can cause this problem?

Comment: Many carriers block several ports on their networks. For example, I am on sprint, and use to be able to SSH into my phone from anywhere (had it on dyndns too), but then sprint blocked incoming ssh requests (and I never messed with changing ports, wasn't that important to me)

Comment: If it's relevant, I'm using port 4567

Comment: probably blocked..  carriers block a lot of incoming traffic on their networks

Comment: Is there another possibility?